# How to determine if a specific input exists using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

My Html

```
<input name="SUBMIT-chn:$INTERNAL_password.pss" title="Select" 
    class="image  selectIcon" type="image" alt="Select" src="docs/pics/select.png">
```

I am trying to use CasperJS to know if this exists and if it does then "Click" it?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var site = 'http://internalsite/username=abc';

var exists;
casper.start(site, function() {
    exists = this.evaluate(function() {
        return __utils__.exists('image selectIcon');
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(exists).exit();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`clientutils.exists()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#exists) expects a CSS selector as an argument. It seems you want to determine whether the input element exists based both of its class attributes.

`'image selectIcon'` is not how you select elements based on the class attribute. A proper CSS selector is this one in that case:

```
'.image.selectIcon'
```

An element can be selected based on a single class (multiple classes are separated by whitespace) by prefixing it with a dot. Selection based on multiple classes on the same element must be written without a space, because a space in the selector means a descendent (such as child) of the previously selected element.

You can use `waitForSelector()` to wait for an element to appear incase the site is dynamically generated and then click it:

```
casper
    .start(url)
    .waitForSelector('.image.selectIcon')
    .thenClick('.image.selectIcon')
    .then(function(){
        // see what happened after the click
        this.capture("screenshot.png");
    })
    .run();
```

Comment: You should learn the basics of CSS selectors before diving into scripting with CasperJS.

Comment: The select icon has a space in it

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple spaces between the classes. That's how CSS selectors work.

Comment: I saw the screenshot is not the entire window. It's very small and most of the page is cut off. Is there anyway to specify the size of the window that I am capturing?

Comment: but there is a larger issue. I am clicking my document but the screenshot shows me something that is not possible unless 1. the screenshot is not the current stage of the web parsing or (2) my casperjs code isn't working as expected.

Comment: The screenshot is always the current stage.

Comment: I used http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-casperjs-capture-method/ to take screenshots of a viewport for the desktop. I'm posting my code above

Comment: I'm gonna stop you right there. Please don't change a question after it has received an answer. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Ok I'll create a new question